# Double arcs from separate transformers

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism

I am replacing six Jacob's Ladders with a 40", open-to-air, Pyrex glass tube with six pairs of evenly, closely-spaced, imbedded tungsten electrodes, connected to six separate 120 volt-15,000 volt transformers. Will those arcs affect each other? I may compress the air.

Comment: My three 1" Pyrex glass tubes will be here tomorrow about this time, I have decided to cut the excess 19" off into smaller chunks, bury them in my hot coal forge then try to drill them with carbide bits. I am running out of time, so get you guesses and suggestions in and I will share my video success or failure!

Answer (score 0):

My three 1" Pyrex glass tubes will be here tomorrow about this time, I have decided to cut the excess 19" off into smaller chunks, bury them in my hot coal forge then try to drill them with carbide bits. I am running out of time, so get you guesses and suggestions in and I will share my video success or failure! – Ron Davison 2 mins ago   edit